# How to replace WMAs with MP3s

Tags: mp3, wma, audio-conversion

Around 60% of my music collection has been ripped using Windows Media Player and thus in WMA format. I want to convert them to MP3 so they are more compatible with other music players.

Is there a way to replace the WMA with and MP3, not duplicate to an MP3 without losing quality?

Comment: As for conversion, any program that uses LAME to convert to MP3 should be good to use.

Comment: I've used MediaMonkey for a while but now I just do something similar to `ffmpeg -i input.wma -ab 32 output.mp3`

Answer (score 2):

We'll do a little trick to create a WMA to MP3 "converter" for you to ease your conversion.
First of all, download FFMpeg. It's free, and you can get it [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-latest-win32-static.7z).

**1)** If your files are in one directory, you can write in batch file:

```
FOR %I IN (*.wma) DO <path to ffmpeg.exe> -i "%I" "%I.mp3"  
ren *.wma.mp3 ????????????????????????????????????????.mp3
delete *.wma
```

Now copy that batch file to directory where are placed your WMA files and run it.

**2)** If you want to select them and convert manually (with drag'n'drop), then write in the batch file:

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -ab 32 %1.mp3  
ren *.wma.mp3 ????????????????????????????????????????.mp3
delete %1
```

Now your "converter" is ready. Drag and drop your files on it to convert files.

Comment: What are all those question marks? Instead of using "%I.mp3" so you end up with .wma.mp3 files you need to rename, just use "%~nI.mp3" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use MP3. MP3 is a lossy compression format, meaning that you lose quality when you use it. Especially if you encode files that have already been encoded once, they will suffer from [generation loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

I'd go with something like AAC if your media player supports it (all Apple devices do). AAC is also lossy, but provides better quality than MP3.

If you're using a Zune, keep them as WMA because they can play those.